# SwiftUI how to use enviromentObject in viewModel init?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I have a base API:

```
class API: ObservableObject {
  @Published private(set) var isAccessTokenValid = false
  @AppStorage("AccessToken") var accessToken: String = ""
  @AppStorage("RefreshToken") var refreshToken: String = ""
  func request1() {}
  func request2() {}
}
```

And it was passed to all views by using `.environmentObject(API())`. So in any views can easily access the API to do the http request calls.

Also I have a view model to fetch some data on the view appears:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var data: [SomeResponseType]
  init() {
    // do the request and then init data using the response
  }
}
struct ViewA: View {
  @StateObject private var model = ViewModel()
  var body: View {
    VStack {
      model.data...
    }
  }
}
```

But in the `init()`, the API is not accessable in the `ViewModel`.

So, to solve this problem, I found 3 solutions:

#### Solution 1: Change API to Singleton:

```
class API: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = API()
   ...
}
```

Also we should change the `enviromentObject(API())` to `enviromentObject(API.shared)`.

So in the ViewModel, it can use API.shared directly.

#### Solution 2: Call the request on the onAppear/task

```
struct ViewA: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var api: API
  @State private var data: [SomeResponseType] = []
  var body: View {
    VStack {}
    .task {
      let r = try? await api.request1()
      if let d = r {
        data = d
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Solution 3: Setup the API to the ViewModel onAppear/task

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var data: [SomeResponseType]
  var api: API?
  setup(api: API) { self.api = api }
  requestCall() { self.api?.reqeust1() }
}
struct ViewA: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var api: API
  @StateObject private var model = ViewModel()
  var body: View {
    VStack {}
    .onAppear {
      model.setup(api)
      model.requestCall()
    }
  }
}
```

---

Even though, I still think they are not a *SwiftUI* way. And my questions is a little XY problem. Probably, the root question is how to refactor my `API`. But I am new to SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 is best. You can also try/catch the exception and set an `@State` for an error message.

Try to avoid using UIKit style view model objects because in SwiftUI the `View` data struct plus `@State` already fulfils that role. You only need `@StateObject` when you need a reference type for view data which is not very often given now we have `.task`.